# Sticker Pack App Sticker size SMALL issue

Tags: ios, ios10, imessage

I am creating a sticker pack application for iOS 10, I created an app using sticker dimension 300x300 and named sticker as sampleSticker@3x.png & in Attributes inspector I had set sticker size as small.

[image: Sticker Size]

But while executing it I am seeing 3 assets in a row instead of 4 and as per the session in [WWDC iMessage](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/204/) there should be 4 assets in a row.

Can anyone help me out in finding the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

I was executing my app in iPhone SE simulator & got to know that it does not support 4 assets in a row that's why it was showing 3 assets in a row when I set it to small.

But when I executed same app on iPhone 6S simulator, it worked like a charm.

So FYI, 4 assets in a row will be seen in devices previous than iPhone 5S & iPhone SE.

Comment: Accept your answer? ;)